# how to create a missing column in a dataframe and place it in the correct order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is my code:

```
holder=['user_ID','name','title','user_access','user_environment','address_flag','address1_line1',
        'address1_line2','address1_line3','address1_line4','address1_line5','address2_line1','address2_line2','address2_line3','address2_line4']

df= pd.read_csv('users.csv', sep=',',usecols=lambda x:x in holder)
```

here i am matching my csv file columns with holder list, how to create a missing column from my csv file in my df but in the correct order as my holder list?

output file looks like this:
|S00045792|||SIRSI|SIRSI||.STREET.Block 3 Street 1|.CITY/STATE.Mishref||.EMAIL.s00045792@test.com|||||||||||||ARAB|||MAIN|CHECKEDOUT|STAFF||||1234||||||||||||||Fatema||Al-Mutawa|||||||||||||||||||||

input file:

[image: csv file]

so if the 'title' column is missing from my csv file, how to create it in the df in the exact same order?

thanks

Comment: Can you please share a sample input of csv file with expected output in dataframe for better understanding?

Comment: check now please

Comment: Please don't post images and links. Instead paste everything as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything as you were already doing then add in the missing columns as such:

```py
for col_name in holder:
    if col_name not in df.columns:
        df[col_name] = ''
```

Then, re-order the columns according to the holder list:

```py
df = df.reindex(columns=holder)
```